# Determining if a sample contains 0 rows for multiple ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

So I've created a simple query that will pass all `OrdID`'s that have orders of 2 or more apples:

```
SELECT ordid 
FROM results 
WHERE ordid IN (12,24,53,21,41,51) 
AND product = 'apples' 
GROUP BY ordid 
HAVING COUNT(ordid) > 1
```

How can I do this for `OrdID`'s that contain 0 apples?(This doesn't work as there is no product on the `OrdID` by apples, so it passes 0 rows.) I'd like it to list all `OrdID`'s that have < 1 products for Apples.

```
SELECT ordid 
FROM results 
WHERE ordid IN (12,24,53,21,41,51)
AND product = 'apples' 
GROUP BY ordid 
HAVING COUNT(ordid) < 1
```

Comment: What do you mean '...OrdID's that contains 0 apples'? Isn't OrdID an identifier? Please add sample data and expected result.

Comment: why doesn't the second query work?

Comment: It would be great if you just post a sample data and the expected results

Comment: @scsimon without testing, I believe the second query wouldn't work because the `product='apples'` filter removes all the rows that aren't 'apples', so after grouping, you won't get ANY `OrdID` with a count(*) of zero because they've been filtered out completely.   That's why the way to get the desired result is either with a NOT EXISTS() or a NOT IN().

Comment: I see @TabAlleman, I was fishing for clarity on the question--I couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce in my machine but I hope that this query should work:

```
SELECT ordid 
FROM results 
WHERE ordid in (12,24,53,21,41,51) 
GROUP BY ordid 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN product = 'apples' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) < 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I switched the HAVING with a COUNT() of the products instead of the orderid since youre trying to count the number of products.

```
SELECT ordid
FROM results 
WHERE ordid in (12,24,53,21,41,51) and product = 'apples'
GROUP BY ordid 
HAVING COUNT(product) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is that you're selecting FROM a table (i.e., limiting to those rows) where what you want to match is what's not in the table (i.e., excluding those rows).  These are opposites.

Instead, flip that around so you're selecting FROM the set of values and then excluding those that match:

```
SELECT ordid FROM (VALUES (12),(24),(53),(21),(41),(51)) AS ordids(ordid)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM results
    WHERE results.ordid = ordids.ordid
    AND results.product = 'apples'
)
```

This will return a result for an `ordid` even if that value never appears in the `results` table at all.

Answer (score -1):

Use the EXISTS() function to get all OrdIDs WHERE there does NOT EXIST a correlated row with `product = 'apples'`